# Laptop fan running often and loudly for no reason since installing ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, dell, fan, inspiron

Since installing Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Inspiron Notebook that came pre-installed with Windows 8 (very unfortunately),

I have been experiencing an increase in the fan's loudness and frequency of running. I have the system load indicator installed, and any time there is a spike (even small spikes) in resource usage, my fan turns on very loudly and continues for about two to five minutes. This happens also sometimes without a spike in resource usage. It happens about every 10 to 20 minutes. As far as I can tell, the temperature of the computer never rises enough to warrant such activity.

I have looked around online and found some advice, but I didn't want to go in and start messing with things right away without someone giving sage advice for my particular problem and laptop. I am a brand new Ubuntu user, and immensely enjoy everything about it thus far, except for the dramatic change in my fan.

How can I fix these issues?

Details about laptop:

> - Inspiron 15 Notebook (Inspiron 3521)[225-3851]
> - Memory: 4GB, DDR3L, 1 DIMM, 1600MHz[370-AAEI]
> - Video Card: Intel® HD Graphics[320-9614]
> - Hard Drive: 500GB 5400 RPM Hard Drive[342-5185]
> - Primary Battery: 4 Cell 40 WHr Battery[312-1395]
> - Processor: 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ i3-3227U processor (3M Cache, 1.9 GHz)[338-BBGF]

Comment: Can you edit in to your question what type of Inspiron notebook it is?

Answer (score 2):

most of times it could be about your graphic card gets warm and because your graphic card is integrated into your cpu the system thinks that cpu gets warm

install `mesa-utils` and `mesa-utils-extras` and reboot
if the problem remains let us know

```
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

( for newcomes: the `$` before this command is just an indicator that tells this command should be entered in a standard user command shell. if you want to use it just press `<ctrl>+<alt>+<t>` and copy-paste without this dollar mark )

Comment: Unable to find mesa-utils-extras. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I used the mesa-utils alone because it was unable to find the extras. It seemed to work, as the fan is operating normally now. Thank you!

Comment: Final update: a week later and fan is back to being loud. Problem not resolved.

Comment: which version of 12.04 you are using?? if you use 12.04.2 or 12.04.3 please downgrade to 12.04.1 or (better) upgrade to 13.04. 13.10 also have some bugs yet and I can't suggest it to install for newcomers.

Answer (score 1):

there are following workaround ,you can try..

1. Cleaning - Physically clean your laptop from inside , dust might have blocked something that tends to rise CPU temperature.
2. Kernel - Update you kernel , to check open termianl by pressing trl+Alt+t and write

   uname -r

Currently after update I am using 3.8.0-33-generic.

1. BIOS - Update your bios in windows , as your new A15 is out for use. thats what worked for me on dell inspiron n5010.

Comment: Good advice. I followed ARF's commands in his answer and it seemed to work out, but I will also use your suggestions.